# Reading message value of an NFC tag -Phonegap/Cordova Application

Tags: javascript, cordova, nfc, phonegap

Am trying out Reading NFC tags but now the "tag.ndefMessage" is being alerted as undefined. Though "tag.id" gives me the ID of the scanned NFC tag. Is there a work around on how to get the actual contents of the NFC tag..

```
     onDeviceReady: function() {
         app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

    // Read NDEF formatted NFC Tags
    nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener  (
        function (nfcEvent) {
            var tag = nfcEvent.tag,
                ndefMessage = tag.ndefMessage;

            // dump the raw json of the message
            // note: real code will need to decode
            // the payload from each record
            alert(JSON.stringify(ndefMessage));

            // assuming the first record in the message has
            // a payload that can be converted to a string.
            alert(nfc.bytesToString(ndefMessage[0].payload).substring(3));
        },
        function () { // success callback
            alert("Waiting for NDEF tag");
        },
        function (error) { // error callback
            alert("Error adding NDEF listener " + JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a different listener to get the NDEF information from the tag Change your code to use `nfc.addNdefListener` instead of `nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener`.

See [nfc.addNdefListener](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc#nfcaddndeflistener) and the github project page for [more information about listeners](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc#multiple-listeners). The [getting started page](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/blob/master/doc/GettingStartedCLI.md) has an updated version of [the code](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/blob/master/doc/GettingStartedCLI.md#edit-indexjs) you need.